# How to fix "Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]" fatal error in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have problem with add new data to database using PDO. 
I have a form where there are several fields. If I leave an empty field then an error pops up.
The problem occurred when mysql was updated on the server. On another server and locally the problem does not appear.
Setting the server in all forms to default values of 0 in the fields will be very difficult.

Database version: 10.3.13-MariaDB-100.cba.1-log - Debian testing

Please, check if you do not complete all the fields and generate an error.

Is it ok when I leave empty input then error generated?

PHP Code:

```
$config = require_once 'config.php';
try {
$db = new PDO(
"mysql:host={$config['host']};dbname={$config['database']};charset=utf8",
$config['user'],$config['password'], 
[PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false, 
 PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
}
catch(PDOException $error)
{
    echo $error->getMessage();
exit('Database error!');
}
if (isset($_POST['dodaj'])) {
    $pole1 = $_POST['pole1'];
    $pole2 = $_POST['pole2'];
    $pole3 = $_POST['pole3'];
    $pole4 = $_POST['pole4'];

    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT into pola VALUES (:pole1, :pole2, :pole3, :pole4)");
    $query->bindValue(':pole1', $pole1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':pole2', $pole2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':pole3', $pole3, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':pole4', $pole4, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $query->execute();
}
```

HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" id="pole1" name="pole1">
    <input type="text" id="pole2" name="pole2">
    <input type="text" id="pole3" name="pole3">
    <input type="text" id="pole4" name="pole4">

    <input type="submit" name="dodaj" value="dodaj">
</form>
```

Database:

pole1 | pole2 | pole3 | pole4

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column `********`.`pola`.`pole3` at row 1 in ************************new 1.php:18 Stack trace: #0 ********************new 1.php(18): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in ******************************new 1.php on line 18

Comment: What are the contents of `$_POST`?

Comment: Make sure the values are actually integers. To be sure, cast them before you bind them `$query->bindValue(':pole1', (int)$pole1, PDO::PARAM_INT);`.

Comment: Please show us the schema for your `pola` table.

Comment: Contents of $_POST - INT. When I leave input empty, then error generated. The field table has only 4 columns: pole1, pole2, pole3, pole4

Comment: Even if your values match the column order in the table, you should list them in the ```INSERT into pola VALUES ``` statement. What if the table is altered in the future? Better safe than spending hours or days looking for the cause of an error. Before saving the values of a form, you should be doing some field validation.

Comment: in the production version so I have done. This code is shortened.

Comment: What is the column definition for `pole1` etc?

Comment: pole1 and another is INT(11), some have NULL, another NOT NULL, but it doesn't change anything. There is problem when I leave empty input in form. When I leave empty field pole4 in form, then error send problem in column pole4.